# Symfony debug toolbar shows invalid entities, how do I debug them

Tags: database, debugging, symfony

Symfony2 debug toolbar shows invalid entities but when I click on it, it only displays the queries, database connections, entity managers and mapping, but no errors whatsoever.

How do I debug those invalid entities?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, you just have to click on the red chip which indicates 3 mapping errors and you'll be able to get the detailed errors in the all bottom of the debug bar, in the **Mapping** area

[image]

Does it help ?

Comment: Yes indeed. I wasn't paying attention. There they are